# Rotate to face point Opengl c++

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

How to get a 3d tetrahedron (ie 3-sided pyramid) rendered with `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)` to face a point.

I need the correct formula so that I can use `glRotatef()` to rotate my object in the x, y, and z coordinates so that it faces a point `(x2, y2, z2)`. But if there is a better way please enlighten me.

Please do not recommend any solutions that use libraries other than the standard C++ library (ie the stuff that comes with the compiler), freeGlut, and Opengl as these are the only libraries I am allowed to use.

Comment: It's easier if you just build the transformation matrix directly. See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24705225/3530129.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!